# Databricks / pyspark: How to get all full directory paths (that have at least one file as content) from Azure Blob storage recursively

Tags: pyspark, databricks, azure-blob-storage

Assume we have a virtual folder structure in an Azure Blob Storage container (that is mounted) as follows:

```
someroot
    2019
        01
            05
                somefile0
    2020
        11
            01
                somefile1
        12
            02
                somefile2
            03
                somefile3
```

As you can see the final level has no subfolders anymore (i.e. there is no combination of folders and files, just files).

How can I can get all full directory paths (excluding file paths) as flat list recursively?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution that returns a flat list of full paths (excluding the file paths):

```
def get_all_directory_paths(base_path: str) -> list:
  """Get all full directory paths

  Parameters
  ----------
  base_path : str
      The starting path to search from

  Returns
  -------
  list
      Flat list of directory paths
  """
  
  all_paths: list = []
  
  def get_paths(base_path: str):
    dir_paths: list = dbutils.fs.ls(base_path)
    subdir_paths_test: list = [p.path for p in dir_paths if p.isDir()]
    if len(subdir_paths_test) == 0:
      all_paths.append(base_path)
    else:
      for p in dir_paths:
        if p.isDir():
          get_paths(p.path)
    
  get_paths(base_path)
  
  return all_paths
```